# Magento 2 How to add attribute options values into dropdown attribute programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I have brand attribute in Magento and want to import all it's options.

Comment: I used the info here to create my own attribute import script https://pearlbells.co.uk/import-attribute-options-magento-2-programmatically/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Create csv with brand and attribute values as shown below
& keep your csv **at M2root/pub/scripts/attribute-value.csv**
[image]

2.Create import-options-value.php at Magento 2 root directory and paste below code & execute script using command line

**php import-options-value.php**

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require '/app/bootstrap.php';

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $entityType = 'catalog_product';
    $directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
    $path  =  $directory->getRoot().'/pub/scripts/';
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
    $eavSetup = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $stores = $storeManager->getStores();
    $storeArray[0] = "All Store Views";
    foreach ($stores  as $store) 
    {
       $storeArray[$store->getId()] = $store->getName();
    }

    $fname = 'attribute-value.csv';
    $optionsExists = array();
    $count = "";
    $file = fopen($path.$fname, "r");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        foreach((array)$data[0] as $attributeCode)
        {
            $option = array();
            $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute($entityType, $attributeCode);
            $option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getAttributeId();
            $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

            foreach($options as $optionCheck) {
                $optionsExists[] = $optionCheck['label'];
            }
            if($data[1]) {
                foreach((array)$data[1] as $key => $value) {
                    $newOptions = array_diff((array)$data[1], $optionsExists );
                    if ($newOptions) {
                        $str = '"'.$value.'"';
                        $option['value'][$str][0]=str_replace('"','', $str);
                        foreach($storeArray as $storeKey => $store) 
                        {
                          $option['value'][$str][$storeKey] = str_replace('"','', $str);
                        }   
                        $count++;
                        echo 'Added value : '.$value.PHP_EOL;
                    }
                }
                $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);

            }
        }
    }
        fclose($file);

    echo "Attribute option values has been associated to brand attribute SUCCESSFULLY Total = ".$count;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the code below. It works on Magento 2.4.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface
 */
protected $attributeOptionManagement;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionLabelInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $optionLabelFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $optionFactory;

/**
 * Update constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface $attributeOptionManagement
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionLabelInterfaceFactory $optionLabelFactory
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterfaceFactory $optionFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface $attributeOptionManagement,
    \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionLabelInterfaceFactory $optionLabelFactory,
    \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterfaceFactory $optionFactory
) {
    $this->attributeOptionManagement = $attributeOptionManagement;
    $this->optionLabelFactory = $optionLabelFactory;
    $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
}

/**
 * Create attribute option
 *
 * @param string $attributeCode
 *
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
 */
public function addOptions(string $attributeCode): void
{
    foreach ($this->labels as $label) {
        var_dump('add option ' . $label);
        /** @var OptionLabel $optionLabel */
        $optionLabel = $this->optionLabelFactory->create();
        $optionLabel->setStoreId(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);
        $optionLabel->setLabel($label);

        $option = $this->optionFactory->create();
        $option->setLabel($label);
        $option->setStoreLabels([$optionLabel]);
        $option->setSortOrder(0);
        $option->setIsDefault(false);

        $this->attributeOptionManagement->add(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $attributeCode,
            $option
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: stackexchange and clean magento code? Really? Whats happening with the world?